# Can not find Ubuntu Computer in Network

Tags: samba, mac

I have Ubuntu, Mac OS X and Windows in same local network. But there is no entry in Mac OS X Network folder about Ubuntu but Windows computer is visible. As far as I know, operating systems let them findable by other computers.

I have installed Samba in Ubuntu and now I can connect Ubuntu via `IP` address from Mac OS X:

```
smb://192.168.2.4
```

But when I try to connect by Ubuntu `hostname` in Mac OS X, it does not succeed:

```
smb://username-SATELLITE-L855
```

I tried the command line to view output in Mac OS X:

```
smbutil view //username@username-SATELLITE-L855
```

It gives below error output:

```
smbutil: server connection failed: No route to host
```

BTW, even after installing Samba in Ubuntu, it is still not visible in Mac OS X Network folder.

How can I make Ubuntu findable by other computers so that I effectively use `hostname` variable in other computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone need it;

It seems that

```
username-SATELLITE-L855
```

is too long as an `hostname`. Converted it to:

```
username-COMP
```

and it solved the problem.